# Register a user only to the root blog - WP Multisite

Tags: multisite, user-registration

I have code to register a user from one of the blogs in WP Multi site:

```
if($userId = wp_create_user($email, $pass, $email)){
    var_dump(get_user_by_email($email));
}
```

The problem is that I want them to be registered NOT for the current site, but for the root site of the network.

I know I can use [remove_user_from_blog](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_user_from_blog), but it seems like a double work.
Is there a way to register a user without attaching them to specific blog ?

Comment: you'd still need to give them a role on the root site, else they have an account but no roles on any sites

Comment: The devhub documentation for `wp_create_user` states that this is just a helper function, and that a more comprehensive function exists, is there a reason you chose `wp_create_user` instead? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_user/